# libtinfo.so doesn't exist in custom LFS system

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm trying to create a custom LFS system. I'm certain I have all the correct packages installed but I'm getting an error when chrooting or booting into it using QEMU.

```
/bin/bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried to created a symlink to libcnurses.so and copying the file from my root system but that fixed nothing. I have also set the x86_64-linux-gnu directory to a symlink to /usr/lib. I've installed the packages glibc, ncurses, vim, bash and coreutils from source.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: @joamag From what i remember i think you needed to compile ncurses with some additional flags but i can't really remember right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile with the following command seemed to give me libtinfo

`../configure --prefix=$LINUX --with-shared --with-termlib --with-ticlib --enable-widec`

Comment: Yes `--with-termlib` is the key element here